Jumping Directly to Next or Previous Folder in Same Level Directory
In Windows 10, I'm looking for a way to directly jump to the next or previous folder on the same level. I currently use the AHK combination (alt > up > right-left > enter), but obviously this fails depending on whether the list view mode of the top directory is active or not.
Therefore, I believe it would be necessary to obtain the list of directories first and then jump to the next (if any) or previous (if any) location. It Turns out I just don't know what to do with this list then, although it seems to be just a matter of creativity, not to mention knowledge. Does anyone protify?

You could get the current path of the Explorer window and then Dir the upper level and find the next or previous sibling folder.
To get the current path of the Explorer window, have a look at this library https://github.com/tdalon/ahk/blob/main/Lib/Explorer.ahk
